# How to add search filter for Table with server side populated data

Tags: google-visualization

I have created google Visualization table with server side Data poplation(Json created in PHP and return to datatable).How to add search filter for this Table? I have seen [Sample Code](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#stringfilter_control)  in Visulaization playgroud. It shows using Control Wrapper and Chart Wrapper.So How to apply this control wrapper for my DataTable(Json data returned from PHP)?

```
function drawmsgtable(users)
    {
        var msgdata = $.ajax({
            url: "http://mysite/phpscripts/msgtable.php?users="+users+"",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        var messagedatatable = new google.visualization.DataTable(msgdata);

        var options={'backgroundColor': 'transparent', 'width': 'auto'};
        $('#table_div').empty();
        var msgTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        msgTable.draw(messagedatatable, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to load the "controls" package

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
```

Then, you need to convert the Table object into a ChartWrapper object, and add a Dashboard object and ControlWrapper object (and HTML div's to hold them - the Dashboard div should contain both the control and table divs, but it is not strictly necessary to have it so).  You bind the control to the table in the dashboard and draw the dashboard

```
function drawmsgtable(users) {
    var msgdata = $.ajax({
        url: "http://mysite/phpscripts/msgtable.php?users=" + users + "",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    var messagedatatable = new google.visualization.DataTable(msgdata);

    var options = {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        width: 'auto'
    };

    $('#table_div').empty();

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dash'));

    var msgTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: options
    });

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        chartType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: {
             filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });

    dashboard.bind([control], [msgTable]);
    dashboard.draw(messagedatatable);
}​
```

**Example HTML:**

```
<div id="dash">
    <div id="control_div"></div>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you want to be able to filter on more than one column, you need additional controls for each column you want to filter.

Comment: Can we remove controls binded to dashboard and re-bind with new controls? This is needed in case of dynamic data from server. Any ideas on this one?