# Dynamic search filters in Google Visualization Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to create filters dynamically based on the data from server?

Something similar to [How to add search filter for Table with server side populated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084775/how-to-add-search-filter-for-table-with-server-side-populated-data) but I would like to know if it is possible to create/remove the binded controls in the dashboard.

```
var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        chartType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: {
             filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });
```

Instead of the above code, I will have something like

```
for (var i=0; i< data.cols.length; i++) {
  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      chartType: 'StringFilter',
      containerId: data.cols[i].id
      options: {...}
  });
}
```

and then bind them to the dashboard after creating all the filters. This is working for the data on the first and repeated on the same type. But when I do it on different data from the server, it is failing saying

> "One or more participants failed to draw()"

So, my question is can the controls created can be removed and re-created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unbind controls, but you should be able to create a data structure to hold a set of controls:

```
var controls = [];
for (var i=0; i< data.cols.length; i++) {
    controls.push(new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        chartType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: data.cols[i].id
        options: {...}
    }));
}

dashboard.bind(controls, [chart1, chart2, ...]);
```

If you get the `"One or more participants failed to draw()"` error, you'll need to debug the code to figure out what is throwing an error, as that is the Dashboard's generic error for "something went wrong somewhere".